# OpenXML SDK -Converting C# to C++/CLI --created file is corrupt and it cannot be opened

Tags: c++-cli, openxml-sdk

I'm trying to write a simple hello world application in C++/CLI to create a Word document which I've posted below

```
int main(array<String^>^ args)
{
    String^ documentFileName=L"Hello4.docx";
    WordprocessingDocument ^myDoc = WordprocessingDocument::Create(documentFileName, WordprocessingDocumentType::MacroEnabledDocument);
    MainDocumentPart^ mainPart = myDoc->AddMainDocumentPart();
    mainPart->Document  = gcnew Document();
    Body^ body = gcnew Body();
    Paragraph^ paragraph = gcnew Paragraph();
    Run^ run_paragraph = gcnew Run();
    DocumentFormat::OpenXml::Wordprocessing::Text^ text_paragraph = gcnew DocumentFormat::OpenXml::Wordprocessing::Text(L"Hello ..asdks");
    run_paragraph->Append(text_paragraph);
    paragraph->Append(run_paragraph);
    body->Append(paragraph);
    mainPart->Document->Append(body);
    mainPart->Document->Save();

    return 0;
}
```

The above program creates hello.docx file but I'm not able to open the created file as it is corrupt.Can you please help me with this

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the exact error you are receiving back? or is there no error, but that `mainPart->Document->Save();` produces nothing?

Comment: @Otaku- I'm not getting any error in that line,But if I run the above code the Hello.docx file is being created but im not able to open the file.it says "the file is corrupt and it cannot be opened"

Comment: It's the `WordprocessingDocument` object that is connected to a file, not the `Document` subobject.  According to [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.packaging.openxmlpackage.close.aspx), you should call `myDoc->Close();`

Comment: @ Ben Voigt - Thanks a lot. it is working now.But the the inserted text is missing in the document, I'll check with that now.Anyways Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ben Voigt- The compiler is not resolving the line mainPart->Document->Append(body); mainPart->Document->Save();. Please help me out of this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a local variable instead of reading back from the property.  e.g.

```
doc = gcnew Document();
mainPart->Document = doc;

//...

doc->Append(body);
doc->Save();
```

Comment: I tried the above answer Its not working. Can you suggest any other solution.